# What does Australia mean by "document of identity" in the list of acceptable alternative travel documents?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork, australia

On the Website of Australian immigration there is a list of travel documents needed to enter the country.

https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Goin/Arrival/Travel-Documents-for-Entry-to-Australia

Under "Travel documents required for all other travellers" (non-Australians/New Zealanders) it says "a valid passport or other acceptable travel document"

Then, under "Other acceptable travel documents", it says "Document of Identity (if holder is not an Australian citizen then a visa is required)"

What does a Document of Identity refer to in this case? I have a hard time believing every single ID document is accepted (as this would imply European ID cards as well, which I highly doubt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That refers specifically to the **Australian Document of Identity**, which is a complicated and obscure legal fudge primarily intended to let people travel to Norfolk Island without a passport:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Document_of_Identity

Norfolk Island is an Australian territory that, until very recently, was largely self-governing and excluded from most Australian taxes and benefits. The government needed a way to track people traveling there, but couldn't insist on a passport (since it's not a foreign country), hence the DOI.

Comment: Isn't that one only issued to Australian citizens? It says a "Document of identity" can be issued to a foreigner, but that a "visa" will then need to be linked to it.

Comment: @Crazydre In rare cases, it can also be issued to non-Australian Commonwealth citizens.